# C89 - error: expected ')' before '*' token

Tags: c, c89

I am getting this error within C.

**error: expected ')' before '*' token**

But cannot trace it.

```
void print_struct(struct_alias *s) //error within this line
{
...
} //end of print method
```

My question is when receiving this error where can the error stem back to? Is it a problem with the function, can it be an error with what is being passed in? *What is the scope of the error?*

Comment: Show some more code so that we can help you better! And on what line number is the error?

Comment: @Rizier123: The question shows us the line on which the error occurs; see the comment.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't recognize the name `struct_alias` as a type name.

For that code to compile, `struct_alias` would have to be declared as a `typedef`, and that declaration would have to be visible to the compiler when it sees the definition of `print_struct`.

(Typedef names are tricky. In effect, they become temporarily user-defined keywords, which is why errors involving them can produce such confusing error messages.)

This is not specific to C89; it applies equally to C90 (which is exactly the same language as C89), to C99, and to C11.

Comment: I looked into it and your right. It wasn't declared as a typedef. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

The error means that here's no such type as `struct_alias` declared in this translation unit.